# How can I make this process end when user inputs "no"

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface

I am trying to ask users a few questions via the CLI, I am coming across a slight problem, when the question in the response function below is answered "No" the product chosen function still goes ahead and prints out the msg.

I realise that this is because I have the else if "No" response so far down the list, however I am not sure where about to place it, as when I previously had it above the code it didnt work either.

```
readline = require('readline-sync');

var rl = require('readline');

var prompts = rl.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

prompts.question("Hi, are you ready to order? (Yes/No) ", function(response) { //This will be the initial display until the customer engages.

var msg = "";

if (response === "Yes") {

    msg = "Great, first lets check your balance";

    console.log(msg);
    process.exit();

}
});

prompts.question("Your balance is currently £0.00, would you like to add credit? (Yes/No) ", function(credit) {

var msg ="";

if(credit === "Yes") {

    var addCredit = "OK, please enter the amount you would like to add. (Format £0.00)";

    bill.question("")

}
else if(credit === "No") {
    msg = "No problem, you will now be taken back to the main menu.";
}

if(addCredit = ("OK, please enter the amount you would like to add. (Format £0.00)")) {

    prompts.question("")

}
})
```

Comment: Please post the errors you are getting.  Are you using Node.js?

Comment: Hi I am using Node.js yes, I tried the solution given below, however I am getting 0 return in the command line, it just starts a new line. Any ideas?

Comment: When checking the response to the first prompt, your just check for "Yes", and in that case set the value of `msg`. Then, whatever the result, you continue with the second question. You should test the first response and act appropriately if it's "No".

Comment: @TedBurgess it will help it your code is formatted properly.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the value returned from prompt method.

Use:

```
var answer = prompt("Hi, are you ready to order? Type Yes or No");
```

//Edit:

I can't see why you are you passing variable (answer) to that function

I would write it that way:

```
function questions() {
    var answer = prompt("Hi, are you ready to order? Type Yes or No");
    if (answer === "Yes") {
        console.log(questions)
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I am still getting 0 return from this in the command line when I run the code, any ideas on what the issue is?

Comment: What do you want to be printed in console by console.log()?

Comment: The aim is to ask someone "Are you ready to order?" They would answer yes or no and then I would move onto the next question

Comment: Now `console.log(questions)` is trying to print function declaration, but this function is while being declared. Use different names.

Like: `var question = "Something?"`, `console.log(question)`, or even instead of `console.log` use `return question`, because this function would print question, and still return 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me, if you have a minute or two would you be able to have a look at the updated edit?

Comment: @MuFFes, the question has changed a bit since you posted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The problem is with the way you nested the conditions. For the second prompt I will suggest you use a `switch` statement. Just so your uses get back a default message.

```
function getCustomerOrder() {
  prompts.question("Hi, are you ready to order? (Yes/No)", function(response) {
    var msg = "";

    if (response === "Yes") {
      msg = "Great, lets get into it!";
      console.log(msg);
      getPurchase();

    }
    else if (response === "No") {
      msg = "No problem, take your time.";
      console.log(msg);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  });
};


function getPurchase() {
  prompts.question("What would you like to purchase? (Please type exact name of Product) ", function(productchosen) {
    var msg = "";

    if (productchosen === "Orange Lucozade") {
      msg = "Orange Lucozade, good choice! That will be £1.00";
    }
    else if (productchosen === "Original Lucozade") {
      msg = "Original Lucozade, good choice! That will be £1.00";
    }
    else if (productchosen === "Apple Lucozade") {
      msg = "Apple Lucozade, good choice! That will be £1.00";
    }

    console.log(msg);
  });
};

// getCustomerOrder();
```

Comment: The "no" does, however the yes crashes the console now

Comment: How about you call a function inside the yes that calls the next prompts

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure how, I had a feeling that there would be a more efficient way of doing it. At the moment my code seems very cluttered and I still have a few more questions to ask, unsure what the best approach to it is

Comment: I have had cases like this before, I used a `async` lib the `waterfall method` in it. Lemme update the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do I need to use any specific libraries or something for this to work? The code I currently have looks like this: http://js.do/code/129983 , but when I run nothing is returned in the command line

Comment: Apart from the `prompts` lib you don't need. The answer I just pasted should work

Comment: Not sure whats happening, it seems to just crash my command line when I try to run with the exact same code, I tried async also, still no luck

Comment: No it doesn't seem to do anything it just starts a new line which allows me to type anything and I have to restart my command line

Comment: You should probably checkout the `prompt package Github issues page`

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but in the code I have just updated can you see what is stopping the questions being continuously asked? The command line just resets after "Great, first lets check your balance"

Comment: Looking at it now.

Comment: Oh! I see you're using Node implementation of prompts. Instead use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt I am recommending it. I've used it for batch scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting 0 feedback from the code suggested earlier, even with reinstalling prompts, this can't half get stressful!

Comment: I suggest you go through their documentation you probably missing something

Comment: Will do, the main problem I am facing now is keeping it all flowing, I am getting the hang of certain parts such as updating the balance, however the program keeps restarting. As a general rule of thumb what is the best way to keep things flowing? Everything in functions, classes etc?

Comment: It depends actually. If you want you program to behave like real objects and relationship use classes. Else use functions if its just actions and no real relationship

Comment: Got there in the end after a long session, turned out process.exit(); was causing the damage.